# How to get the set of features with the least sum of correlation in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `correlation matrix` which is a `pandas` dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'vars': ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c', 'col_d'],
                   'col_a': [1, 0.9, 0.04, 0.03],
                   'col_b': [0.9,1,0.05,0.03],
                   'col_c': [0.04, 0.05, 1, -0.04],
                   'col_d': [0.03, 0.03, -0.04,1]})
```

I would like to get a set of 3 (out of the 4) variables, that the sum of their absolute correlation is the minimum.

My solution is:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

test_cols = ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c', 'col_d']
sum_l = {}
for l in list(itertools.combinations(test_cols, 3)):
#     print(l)
#     print(list(itertools.combinations(l, 2)))
    sum_l2 = 0
    for l2 in list(itertools.combinations(l, 2)):
#         print(l2)
#         print(l2[0])
#         print(l2[1])
        sum_l2 += np.abs(foo.query('vars == @l2[0]')[l2[1]].values[0])
    sum_l[l] = sum_l2
print(sum_l)
print(min(sum_l, key=sum_l.get))
```

Is there a way to do it more efficiently ? To avoid the `for` loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools` to create the combinations and then `reindex` down to the smaller correlation matrixes, so you only need one loop. Then because these are symmetric and you want to ignore the diagonal use `np.tril` to `0` the elements you don't want to include. Finally take the absolute value and sum.

```
import numpy as np

foo = foo.set_index('vars')

d = {}
for cols in itertools.combinations(foo.columns, 3):
    arr = foo.reindex(cols).reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()
    d[cols] = np.abs(np.tril(arr, k=-1)).sum()

pd.Series(d)
#col_a  col_b  col_c    0.99
#              col_d    0.96
#       col_c  col_d    0.11
#col_b  col_c  col_d    0.12


# And the smallest
pd.Series(d).nsmallest(1)
#col_a  col_c  col_d    0.11
```

Comment: thats 20 times faster already in a toy example :)

Comment: @quant can you test my version for fun?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pandas-less version that should be faster:

```
foo = foo.set_index('vars')
pairs = foo.where(np.triu(foo, k=1).astype(bool)).stack().abs()
combinations = list(itertools.combinations(pairs.index, 3))
sums = [sum(map(pairs.get, i)) for i in combinations]
combinations[np.argmin(sums)]
```

output:

```
(('col_a', 'col_c'), ('col_a', 'col_d'), ('col_b', 'col_d'))
```

If you want the single value columns:

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain(*combinations[np.argmin(sums)]))
```

Comment: This gives as answer `{'col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c', 'col_d'}`, which shouldnt be the case, because it is supposed to return only 3 features. It gets the pairs correctly, but when you take the single value columns it outputs all 4 of them